# Pandas: Comparing a row value and modify next column's row values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have this Pandas Dataframe:

```
    A                             B
0   xyz                          Lena
1   NaN                          J.Brooke
2   NaN                          B.Izzie
3   NaN                          B.Rhodes
4   NaN                          J.Keith        
.....
```

I want to compare the values of column B such that if row value begins with B then in it's adjacent row of column A new should be written and similarly if J then old. Below is what I'm expecting:

```
    A                             B
0   xyz                         Lena
1   old                         J.Brooke
2   new                         B.Izzie
3   new                         B.Rhodes
4   old                         J.Keith        
.....
```

I'm unable to understand how I can do this. To begin with I can use `startswith()` but then how to compare one row value and then to have the required field values right in the adjacent row of another column?
This is a small case I'm trying a lot og messier things...Pandas is indeed powerful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) if need set new values by conditions:

```
m1 = df['B'].str.startswith('B')
m2 = df['B'].str.startswith('J')
```

If need also test missing values chain conditions by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
m1 = df['B'].str.startswith('B') & df['A'].isna()
m2 = df['B'].str.startswith('J') & df['A'].isna()
```

---

```
df['A'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['new','old'], df['A'])
print (df)
     A         B
0  xyz      Lena
1  old  J.Brooke
2  new   B.Izzie
3  new  B.Rhodes
4  old   J.Keith
```

Or use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[m1, 'A'] = 'new'
df.loc[m2, 'A'] = 'old'
```

Comment: How to assign Nan for rows which neither start with J or B ? I'd want to have Nan value in place of xyz. How to achieve that?

Comment: @HAH - Do you think `df['A'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['new','old'], np.nan)` ?

Comment: @HAH - Last value in `np.select` is default parameter - it return, if not match any condition  in list, here `[m1, m2]`

Answer (score 2):

try using loc
I added .isnull() check because if already something exist in colA would not be replaced,but if you don't want you can ignore that check

```
import pandas 
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'colA':["xyz",np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                   "colB":['Lena','J.Brooke','B.Izzie','B.Rhodes','J.Keith']})

df.loc[(df['colA'].isnull()) &(df['colB'].str.startswith("B")),"colA"] = "new"
df.loc[(df['colA'].isnull()) &(df['colB'].str.startswith("J")),"colA"] = "old"
print(df)
```

```
   colA      colB
0  xyz      Lena
1  old  J.Brooke
2  new   B.Izzie
3  new  B.Rhodes
4  old   J.Keith
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pd.Series.fillna`:

```
df['A'].fillna(df['B'].str[0].replace({'J': 'old', 'B': 'new'}))
```

Output:

```
     A         B
0  xyz      Lena
1  old  J.Brooke
2  new   B.Izzie
3  new  B.Rhodes
4  old   J.Keith
```